# Removing 'gmail.com' from the 'from' when using gmail smtp and phpmailer

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am using PhpMailer to send emails via gmail smtp. And while `$mail->setFrom('jack.schmitt@domain.com','Jack Schmitt');` does insert 'Jack Schmitt' as the name of the sender, it is still including my smtp username. So the recipient will see something like this: `Jack Schmitt<smtp_user@gmail.com>` in the From: line

Is there a way to have it say `Jack Schmitt<jack.schmitt@domain.com>` in stead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send using arbitrary from addresses, because that would usually be forgery. You can only send *from* your account address or predefined (in gmail settings) aliases. This is [a gmail feature covered in their docs](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).